# What kind of "effects" does Safari add to apple-touch-icon?

Tags: safari, favicon, apple-touch-icon

I've been seeing a lot of websites saying that you can disable the effects Safari puts on a apple-touch-icon by adding "-precomposed" to the end.

What "effects" exactly does Safari add to the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gloss and a drop shadow are added when "-precomposed" is not appended to the tag.